# How to set SQL condition precedence for two different conditions

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm having two different tables '**TABLE1**' and '**TABLE2**'. Both of these tables have same column name - '**IS_PDF**'.

RE TABLE1.IS_PDF value, I retrieved the required details using **select** statement where I added where clause like below.

```
select * from TABLE1 where TABLE1.IS_PDF = 'Y';
```

Similarly, I can get the values for TABLE2 as well where TABLE2.IS_PDF = 'Y'

Now, my task is to have one select statement to get the details from both tables '**TABLE1**' and '**TABLE2**' by setting a **precedence on below condition # 1**.

1. If **TABLE1.IS_PDF = 'Y'**, return records matching same condition.
2. If **TABLE1.IS_PDF = 'N'** but **TABLE2.IS_PDF = 'Y'** then return records matching same condition.
3. If both have IS_PDF = 'N', return nothing.

I used below Select statement but getting Above conditions # 1 and 2 at the same time only.

```
select * from TABLE1, TABLE2
where
(TABLE1.IS_PDF = 'Y') or (TABLE2.IS_PDF = 'Y' and TABLE1.IS_PDF = 'N' )
```

Please guide on the same.
Thanks

Comment: Sample data would really help.

Comment: Also PKs and FKs

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.is_pdf = 'Y'
union all
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where t2.is_pdf = 'Y' and
      not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.is_pdf = 'Y' and t1.?? = t2.??);
```

The `??` represents the column(s) used for matching between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response.

Sample code-

```
select TABLE1.IS_PDF, TABLE2.IS_PDF, TABLE1.ID, TABLE1.GLOBAL_ID, TABLE1.title, 
from TABLE1, TABLE2
where TABLE1.USER_ID = 82340
and TABLE1.NAME = 'INDIA'
and (TABLE1.IS_PDF = 'Y') or (TABLE2.IS_PDF = 'Y' and TABLE1.IS_PDF = 'N' )
```

I need to set a precedence on below condition # 1. If condition # 1 meets, it's fine. Otherwise go for #2 then #3.

1. If TABLE1.IS_PDF = 'Y', return records matching same condition.
2. If TABLE1.IS_PDF = 'N' but TABLE2.IS_PDF = 'Y' then return records matching same condition.
3. If both have IS_PDF = 'N', return nothing.

Comment: . . I suspect that you should really be editing the question with this information.  Then you can delete tis answer.